# return a value of a map

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm fetching a specific data set form firebase realtime database and try to return a single value of the map. It works to print the variable in the map, but I can't return it.

in this case, the function get_Name should return the value "Michael"

realtime database structure:

group 
      -MdXLzrGo4qIGO67ujNM 
      -MdXT0oysMDxqFQ5KurB 
      -Me4Kpz1He0v1QuH2e7Z 
              castDate: "" 
              castLocation: "" 
              castName: "Michael"

```
void initState() {
   test = get_Name("-Me4Kpz1He0v1QuH2e7Z");
   print(test); 

    super.initState();
}

get_Name(String GroupID){
    var Name;
    DatabaseReference db;
    db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("group");
    db.orderByKey().equalTo(GroupID).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> DB_value = snapshot.value;
      DB_value.forEach((key,values) {
        Name =values["castName"];
        print(Name); // prints "Michael"
      });
    });
   return Name; //returns "NULL"
  }
```

thanks in advance 
Bernhard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current code is a missing understanding that `.then()` is going to be executed asynchronously and after you have returned `Name`.

Try instead rewrite the method to something like this where we mark the method as `async` which allows us to use `await` instead of using `.then()` which makes the code a lot more simpler to understand:

```
Future<String> get_Name(String GroupID) async {
  String name;
  final db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("group");
  final snapshot = await db.orderByKey().equalTo(GroupID).once();

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> DB_value = snapshot.value;
  DB_value.forEach((key, values) {
    name = values["castName"] as String;
    print(name); // prints "Michael"
  });

  return name; //returns "NULL"
}
```

The return value of the method are `Future<String>` (`Future` is required for `async` marked methods) to indicate that the method calling `get_Name` needs to also `await` the answer since everything is going to be asynchronously executed.

Answer (score 0):

Returning from inside of the then block should do it.

```
get_Name(String GroupID){
    var Name;
    DatabaseReference db;
    db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("group");
    db.orderByKey().equalTo(GroupID).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> DB_value = snapshot.value;
      DB_value.forEach((key,values) {
        Name =values["castName"];
        print(Name); // prints "Michael"
      });
      return Name; 
    });
  }
```

But also you are assigning the Name many times in the loop. Is that intended? Else you should use arrays in push all the items in it.